# Algorithm to maximise zeros in a matrix, without multiplications of rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is potentially a very easy question. I'd like to know if there is a common algorithm for performing addition/subtraction between elements of a matrix while maintaining their overall scale, but minimising the number of non-zero values. I'd like to use such an algorithm to minimise the number of transactions required between groups of people that owe each other.

The values owed between each person in the group are represented in a 2D matrix of dimension NxN, where N is the number of people in the group. The diagonals are zero, as a person doesn't owe themself anything.

Starting matrix:

```
A    B    C
0    3    1  # A owes
0    0    2  # B owes
0    0    0  # C owes
```

In text:

- A owes B `$3`
- A owes C `$1`
- B owes C `$2`
- A pays `$4`, receives `$0` (total `-$4`)
- B pays `$2`, receives `$3` (total `+$1`)
- C pays `$0`, receives `$3` (total `+$3`)

The solution to minimise transactions is to sequentially find submatrices where people owe each other, and try to cancel debts by adding/subtracting. For example, if A owes B, A owes C and B owes C, then A's debt to B can be cancelled by adding it to A's debt to C and subtracting it from B's debt to C.

Solution following the above example:

```
A    B    C
0    0    4  # A owes
0    0    0  # B owes
0    1    0  # C owes
```

In text:

- A owes C `$4`
- C owes B `$1`
- A pays `$4`, receives `$0` (total `-$4`)
- B pays `$0`, receives `$1` (total `+$1`)
- C pays `$1`, receives `$4` (total `+$3`)

As you can see, the totals in both case are the same: each person will have to pay the same total amount and will receive the same total amount, but potentially to/from different people.

I think I could implement such an algorithm in Python quite easily, but I wonder if this is already a common linear algebra operation that I could use a library function for. Does such an algorithm have a name?

Observation: as a value at element [a, b] is equivalent to the negative of that value at [b, a] (A paying a value to B is equivalent to B paying -value to A), the final matrix can always be made triangular.

Comment: Do you mean the fewest number of non-zero entries possible or the least total number of dollars transacted?

Comment: @mathreadler least number of non-zero entries, which would be equivalent to the least number of required transactions (total dollars transacted doesn't matter).

Comment: okay I see. Then I think cvx would work well enough for your purposes as it has a fast solver for $L_1$ cost terms which can be used to approximate $L_0$ which is what you want if you want to have as many zeros as possible. Or you can probably do it with iteratively reweighted least squares, reweighting stuff close to 0 to be even more pushed towards 0 than they were last iteration.